# How to display image in select2 dropdown with option group?

Tags: php, yii2, jquery-select2

I am working in yii2. I have one form. In that i have one dropdown. I need to display all dropdown option with name and image with option group.

Images and name are displaying. But how to display all option with option group.

**View file :**

```
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-5">
       <?= $form->field($model,'targetfish_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Targetfish::find()->all(),'id','image'),
          ['multiple'=>'multiple']) ?>
  </div>
```

**View File Script :**

```
<?php
$this->registerJs('
    function formatState (fish) {
      if (!fish.id) { return fish.text; }
      var $fish = $(
        "<span><img src=/www/target_fish_pic/"+fish.text+ " class=img-flag style=width:50px />"+  fish.text +"</span>"
      );
      return $fish;
    };

    $("#boatinformation-targetfish_id").select2({
        placeholder: "Select Targeted Fish",
      templateResult: formatState,
      templateSelection: formatState,
    });

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#boatinformation-in_water_slip").change();
});
$("#boatinformation-in_water_slip").on("change",function(){
    if( $(this).val()==="0"){
        $(".slip_controls").hide()
        $(".guest_controls").show()
    }
    else{
        $(".slip_controls").show()
        $(".guest_controls").hide()
    }
});
');
```

How to create option group from above code ? And also in dropdown value it is printing imgae name not value(because of this line -> `map(Targetfish::find()->all(),'id','image')`). May I take id name and image ?

Answer (score 1):

Select2 comes with AJAX support built in, using jQuery's AJAX methods. that will help you to display image with your requirement.

You can check more with below link.

https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax

Answer (score -1):

```js
<script>
    function fmtState (state) {
        if (!state.id) { return state.text; }
        var $state = $(
            '<span>'+
            '<img src="images/flags/' +
            state.element.value.toLowerCase() +
            '.png" class="img-flag" /> ' +
            state.text +
            '</span>'
        );
        return $state;
    }
</script>
```

```html
<div class="input-control" data-template-result="fmtState" data-role="select">
    <select>
        <option>option</option>
        ...
        <option>option</option>
    </select>
</div>
```